# How do I support shelving

Tags: woodworking

What is the recommended distance between brackets when supporting a particleboard shelf 11 3/4 inches deep by 3/4 inches thick to support books?

Answer (score 1):

There's no single answer, since it depends on the expected load. Use a calculator like [this one](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator.htm)